# Want to use g_timeout_add. Have to run a glib main loop?

Tags: c, callback, timeout, glib

I am trying to add a callback using g_timeout_add ( timevalue , Func, values passed in Func) to get some status or print something after timevalue.

I am not able to see it. Do I have to call a main loop also? 
OR any other type of function to get it working ?

Answer (score 1):

`g_timeout_add` is a wrapper for creating a `GSouce` which will be used/worked on in the mainloop. So commonly a `GMainLoop` is run, or in more complex cases, `g_main_loop_iteration` (or similar) is called in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a main-loop as well. This can be either implicit (e.g. in a gtk+ app it's created for you), or explicitly (use g_main_loop_new and g_main_loop_run), ie:

```
loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, TRUE)

g_timeout_add ( ... )

g_main_loop_run (loop)

...
```