# concept of gobject and how can we use it in gstresmer application devolepment

Tags: c, streaming, gstreamer, gobject

I am developing a `gstreamer` application. There are some basic concepts I don't understand. Can anyone please explain the concept of `g Object`? Also what is `gobject initialisation`, `gobject` properties, `gobject` casting, `gobject` referencing, and please provide a good link too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When learning `gstreamer`, you may not need to know/ learn about `GObject`. In one basic line `GObject`, and its lower-level type system, GType, are used by GTK+ and most GNOME libraries to provide: object-oriented C-based APIs

However if you still want to know the *connection* it has with `gstreamer`. I can count the following simple examples,

1..   When you check the hierarchy of any `GstElement` or any other `gst` type, you will see they all are derived from `GObject`, like the one below. This means all the methods used and defined for GObject can also be used for `GstObject` etc.

[image]

2.. Even though the only header file included is gst.h. When we check code of gst.h it internally has already included glib.h.

[image]

3.. While you go through tutorials, there can be some functions which are not defined in gstreamer sdk but are imported/included using glib.h headers and linked using glib.so.
You can refer gstreamer [tutorials](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorials).

**g_object_set** (data.source, "uri", "http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);
**g_timeout_add** (200, (GSourceFunc) cb_print_position, pipeline);  [more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394954/want-to-use-g-timeout-add-have-to-run-a-glib-main-loop) ]
**g_main_loop_run** (loop);

Like I said these signal connect and object set functions are intuitive and need not to be known to learn gstreamer.

...
As you asked here is an [intro](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.39/chapter-intro.html) to GObject.

Answer (score 0):

`GObject` is the fundamental type providing the common attributes and methods for all object types in `GTK+`, `Pango` and other libraries based on `GObject`. The `GObject` class provides methods for object construction and destruction, property access methods, and signal support.

Here are some links with more detailed explanation:
https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html
https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/chapter-gobject.html